# to plot the values of coordinates in first unit quadrant in matlab

Tags: matlab, graph

I have two row vectors of size 1x1024 and they consist of values in the range [0 1]. I want to plot all the points on the graph within first unit quadrant in MATLAB. Please help me out to draw this graph.

Comment: Is your two row vectors represent (x,y) coordinates or do you want to plot both against x as two plots?

Comment: They represent (x,y) coordinates.

Comment: `plot(xdata, ydata, '.'), axis([0 1 0 1])` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ydata = ydata(xdata>=0 && xdata<=1);
xdata = xdata(xdata>=0 && xdata<=1);

plot(xdata, ydata);
```